# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID Error

Tags: vb.net, 32bit-64bit, com-interop

I get this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {819F123A-B24A-4EB8-BED1-B5DFC5CB5194} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

For below code:

```
Public WithEvents vp2 As VSPrinter8Lib.VSPrinter
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    vp2 = New ``VSPrinter8Lib.VSPrinter
End Sub
End Class
```

I exhausted with all option like running it on 32 bit mode in VS, copying in syswow64 folder, converting dll to 32 bit but no luck. I am not getting 32 bit version of "VSPrinter8Lib" on the internet, neighter i am able to convert/register it to 32 bit using regsvr32 (Getting error Entry point was not found) nor able to find CLSID in registery (since it doen't come with installer). Kind of strucked since last 1 week. Seeking for help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could run procmon from sysinternals, filter on your .exe name, and check where/what/when the CLSID is read. If there's nothing where it looks, then registration doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Did you install the package that it came in?  A quick Google suggests that this is a ComponentOne product, so there is presumably a full installer that will take care of the necessary registration.  It looks like it's pre-.NET (they have a successor .NET product), so I think it would be 32-bit only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve issue. When using an ActiveX control is a .NET project, Visual Studio will create a "bubble" of ActiveX to allow the control to operate and then create an interop layer to allow your .NET project to communicate with the activex control. In my example, i was attempting to register the interop layer Visual Studio created (Interop.VSPrinter8Lib.dll) and not the actual ActiveX controls itself. Thus you need to get ActiveX OCX file for desired Introp DLL e.g. vsprint8.ocx on place of Interop.VSPrinter8Lib.dll and Please ensure all those files are in the directory where your registering the OCX files (it should be in C:\Windows\SysWow64 if on a 64-bit machine). In addition, please ensure the command line (cmd.exe) is run as an admin. 
e.g. I kept OCX file in C:\Vineet\vsprint8.ocx and would run below command
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe C:\Vineet\vsprint8.ocx